# javax.validation.constraints.NotNull not work for java.time.Instant in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

Constraint @NotNull doesn't work for field instance of Instant after migration from java to kotlin. I mean that in java because of this constraint I got 422 in case of updatedAt was null but in kotlin I have 400. Could you give me some clues why is that and how I can resolve it?

```
data class User(
@NotNull
val updatedAt: Instant
)
```

Comment: A minimal code sample would be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by ‘doesn't work’?

Comment: I improved my description

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `updatedAt` property is defined to be of non-nullable type `Instant`, it is not possible that it is null, and thus, it is not possible that the `@NotNull` constraint fails. Before it can fail, there will probably be an `IllegalArgumentException` when some mechanism tries to set the property to null.

That `IllegalArgumentException` in turn is then probably translated by some exception handler into a Rest code of 400, while whatever exception that would be thrown by checking a violation of the constraint would be translated into a Rest code of 422.

You should try to make the property nullable in order to allow the property to become null which can then be checked to violate the `@NotNull` constraint:

```
data class User(
   @NotNull
   val updatedAt: Instant?
)
```

Alternatively, you could try to catch the exception that is thrown when setting the value of `updatedAt` and replace it. Or, you could write an exception handler that returns Rest code 422 instead of 400. But since I do not know much about your technology stack, I cannot give you more details on that.